# Word VBA - insert second table, then start populating it

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

in my Access VBA I have the following creating and populating a Word Table without issue.

```
oWord.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=oDoc.Bookmarks("\endofdoc").Range, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=5
   rs.MoveFirst
   r = 0 'current row counter

  'start the recordset loop reserving the top two rows for header type stuff.
   With oWord.Selection
    .TypeText "Control Identifier"
    .MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
    .TypeText "Control Name"
    .MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
    .MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
    .MoveRight Unit:=wdCell

    'first data row
    .MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
    .TypeText rs("Control_Main")
    .MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
    .TypeText rs("Title")
    .MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
    .MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
    .MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
    ......
```

and so on when the table is completed I insert a page break and some text, then I insert a second table.

```
oWord.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=oDoc.Bookmarks("\endofdoc").Range, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=3   
rs.MoveFirst   
With oWord.Selection
  'first data row
  .MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
  .TypeText rs("Control_main")
  .MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
  .TypeText rs("Title")
  .MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
  ......
```

The second table gets created but nothing populates in it.  If I put `oWord.Selection.Style = "Table Grid"` after my second table creation - it creates a grid around the first table but no additional text or rows are added to the first table.

I know I can do a `set oTable =` type of table creation, but then when I try and select it, it seems to select from the Word.Document instead of the Word.Application and my subsequent with .Selection doesn't act right for .moveright for my dynamic creation.

Any ideas where i'm going awry?

---Update post working ---
A very special thank you to @freeflow for his patience and assistance.  His code was great, I just needed to do a slight tweak mainly with this part.
...
The move unit wdRow worked, but without the additional row it exited the table.  I also had problems with referring to .Cells(2) for 2nd column in that row - but moving first then entering text worked just fine.

this.

```
myRow.Move unit:=wdRow, Count:=1
myRow.Cells(1).Range.Text = rs("Control_Main")
myRow.Cells(2).Range.Text = rs("Title")
```

became this.

```
  oDoc.Tables(1).Rows.Add
  myRow.Move Unit:=wdRow, Count:=1
  myRow.Cells(1).Range.Text = rs("Control_main")
  myRow.Move Unit:=wdCell, Count:=1
  myRow.Cells(1).Range.Text = rs("Title")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are not selecting the specific table on which you wish to work. 
For your first and subsequent tables try

```
Dim myRange as Word.range
with oWord.ActiveDocument.Tables
    set myRange=.Item(.Count).Range
end with

with myRange.Tables(1)

etc
```

Update 2020/Apr/30

I hope the following update is clearer to follow.

```
rs.MoveFirst
r = 0 'current row counter

'start the recordset loop reserving the top two rows for header type stuff.
'Add the first table at the end of the document
oDoc.Tables.Add Range:=oDoc.Bookmarks("\endofdoc").Range, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=5

'set myRow to the range of the first row in the last table in the document
Dim myRow As Word.Range
' .First is sugar for .Item(1)
Set myRow = oDoc.Tables.Item(oDoc.Tables.Count).Range.Rows.First.Range

myRow.Cells(1).Range.Text = "Control Identifier"
myRow.Cells(2).Range.Text = "Control Name"

myRow.Move unit:=wdRow, Count:=1

'first data row - its not clear from your code if you are entering data into the first column or not
' so the 1 and 2 below may need adjusting
' such is the difficulties introduced by emulating keyboard movements.
myRow.Cells(1).Range.Text = rs("Control_Main")
myRow.Cells(2).Range.Text = rs("Title")

etc

'add the next table at the end of the document

oDoc.Tables.Add Range:=oDoc.Bookmarks("\endofdoc").Range, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=5

'set myRow to the range of the first row in the last table in the document
Dim myRow As Word.Range
' .First is sugar for .Item(1)
Set myRow = oDoc.Tables.Item(oDoc.Tables.Count).Range.Rows.First.Range

myRow.Cells(1).Range.Text = "Control Identifier"
myRow.Cells(2).Range.Text = "Control Name"

myRow.Move unit:=wdRow, Count:=1

'first data row - its not clear from your code if you are entering data into the first column or not
' so the 1 and 2 below may need adjusting
' such is the difficulties introduced by emulating keyboard movements.
myRow.Cells(1).Range.Text = rs("Control_Main")
myRow.Cells(2).Range.Text = rs("Title")

etc
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  When I change to that method I get the error "Method or Data member not found" on the first instance of .TypeText
`oWord.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=oDoc.Bookmarks("\endofdoc").Range, numRows:=1, numColumns:=5
  With oWord.ActiveDocument.Tables
    Set oRange = .Item(.Count).Range
  End With`
...
`With oRange.Tables(1)
    .TypeText "Control Identifier"`

Comment: Then you need to specify the cell in which you wish to enter text. e.g .Cells.Item(1).Range.Text.  Once you have specified the first cell the other relative moves should be OK.

Comment: i'm sorry man, i'm just i guess being real thick about it.   The MS docs say that .moveright is for the selection object which we cover with the `With oRange.Tables(1)`  I  understand you're saying get into that first cell first then move around per normal.  but if I do. `.cells.item(1).Range.Text` below the `with oRange.Tables(1)`, I get method not found error.  The docs show me that .cells is part of selection but give examples of selection.cells(1).

Comment: with oRange.Tables.Item(1).Range  Then on the next line .Cells.Item(1).Range

Comment: I try that, then I get the method or data not found on the line following. (the .moveright)
`    With oRange.Tables.Item(1).Range
      .Cells.Item(1).Range.Text = "Control identifier"
    .MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
    .TypeText "Control Name"`

Comment: I think we are getting confused between direct cell referencing and relative cell referencing.  Se my updated exmaple.  No need for .moveright

Comment: oh,  i see what you're doing there.  okay let me give it a shot - there's a lot to convert over.

Comment: thank you freeflow.  i got it going and updated my original post with a slight tweak i needed to do.  thank you for sticking with me.